# Javascript has StackOverflow in IE but not Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a class that is basically a native Javascript Array, but it raises events when items are added or removed.

```
hb.extend( {
Classes: {
    Collection: hbClass.inherit({
        init: function (arr) {
            // get the functions we want to retain
            var _on = this.on,
                _trigger = this.trigger,
                _push = this.push,
                _remove = this.remove,
                _reset = this.reset,
                _from = this.fromArray,
                _watch = this.watch;

            // Set the object up as an Array
            this.__proto__ = Array.prototype;

            // get the Array functions we want to use
            this.arrPush = this.push;

            // reapply the old functions
            this.push = _push;
            this.remove = _remove;
            this.reset = _reset;
            this.fromArray = _from;
            this.on = _on;
            this.trigger = _trigger;
            this.watch = _watch;

            if (arr && (arr.length && typeof arr !== "string")) this.fromArray(arr, true);
        },

        fromArray: function (arr, stopEvent) {
            this.reset();
            for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
                this.arrPush(arr[i]);
            }
            if (!stopEvent) this.trigger('change', this);
        },

        push: function () {
            this.arrPush.apply(this, arguments);
            this.trigger('add', this);
            this.trigger('change', this);
            return this;
        },

        remove: function (from, to) {
            var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
            this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;

            this.arrPush.apply(this, rest);
            this.trigger('remove', this);
            this.trigger('change', this);
            return this;
        },

        reset: function () {
            this.length = 0;
            this.trigger('change', this);
            this.trigger('remove', this);
        }
    })
}
});
```

There may be better ways to do it, but it works for me.......except in IE.
In IE at the line `this.arrPush.appy(this, arguments);` under the `push` method, it hits a Stack Overflow error.
Specifically:

> SCRIPT28: Out of stack space

But this does NOT occur in Firefox or Chrome.
Anyone have any advice?
***EDIT***
Trigger code:

```
this.hbClass.prototype.trigger = function(type, data, context) {
    var listeners, handlers, i, n, handler, scope;
    if (!(listeners = this.listeners)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(handlers = listeners[type])){
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0, n = handlers.length; i < n; i++){
        handler = handlers[i];

        if (handler.method.call(
            handler.context, this, type, data
        )===false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `this.push` to `_push` and then just reassigning that back (`this.push = `_push`).

Comment: @natlee75 : IE 9.  Also, in `init`, the line `this.__proto__ = Array.prototype;` is basically setting `Collection` to BE a native Javascript Array, at which point it loses all of its functions.  So then I reapply the ones that I want to keep (most of which are inherited from hbClass).

Comment: Why are you using `this.__proto__` and not `this.prototype`? Just curious... (I know what your assignment statement does just read too fast haha ;-).

Comment: @natlee75 : Honestly....I don't remember.  I think doing `this.prototype` didn't work for some reason....but I wrote this quite a while ago (and forgot to test it in IE).

Comment: Did you notice the possibly unintended result that the "array" contains not just what you push into it but also references to each of the methods you assign to it?

Comment: @natlee75 : I did notice that later, though I'm unsure of what causes it.  However, when looping through the array with a for loop, only items added via 'push' are looped through.  If you have suggested improvements, feel free to email me (jamesw at gmail) so we could discuss it there instead of in this question.

Comment: Is there any way you could post more information about the code? It could be tough to diagnose this just from what you've posted here. For example, does `trigger` do anything other than set off an event?

Comment: @natlee75 : See updated post with trigger code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably this line:

```
this.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
```

as `__proto__` is not supported in some versions of IE.  It has been codified in the ES6 specification, but that isn't implemented in some versions of IE.  I don't understand exactly how your code works, but the safe way to set a prototype is like this:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ff99G/

```
function myClass() {
    // add new methods to this instance in the constructor
    this.fromArray = function() {};
};
// become an array and get all its methods
myClass.prototype = Array.prototype;


var x = new myClass();
```

Here's an example of the kind of thing you're doing using `.prototype` that works in IE:

```
function log(msg) {
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = msg;
    result.appendChild(div);
}

function myClass() {
    var _push = this.push;
    this.count = function() {
        return this.length;
    }
    this.trigger = function(type, name) {
        var str = type;
        if (name) {
            str += ", " + name;
        }
        log(str);
    }
    this.push = function() {
        var retVal = _push.apply(this, arguments);
        this.trigger("change", "push");
        return retVal;
    }
};

// become an array and get all its methods
myClass.prototype = Array.prototype;


var x = new myClass();

x.push("foo");
x.push("whatever");
log(x.count());
```

Comment: I just figured that out about `__proto__`.  I'll mess around with my code to see if I can just use `.prototype` instead.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright - I added a working demo to my answer that works in IE7+.